# Is it possible to pass the same optional arguments to multiple functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, optional-arguments

I want to ask if there is a way to prevent unnecessary duplicate of code when passing the same arguments into a function's optional arguments.

Hopefully the following example provides a good idea of what I am trying to do:

```
def f(arg1):
    def g(optional_1=0, optional_2=0, optional_3=0):
        return arg1+optional_1+optional_2+optional_3
    return g

b, c = 2, 3
f1 = f(1)
f2 = f(2)
calc_f1 = f1(optional_2=b, optional_3=c)
calc_f2 = f2(optional_2=b, optional_3=c)
```

As you can see, f1 and f2 only differ in the arg1 passed into f and afterwards I call them with the same variables for the same optional arguments.
It is fine when the code is short, but when I have over 10 optional arguments, it becomes unnecessarily long and redundant.
Is it possible to do something like

```
optional_variable_pair = #some way to combine them
calc_f1 = f1(optional_variable_pair)
calc_f2 = f2(optional_variable_pair)
```

so I get a more succinct and easy to read code?

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand your question, but have you tried using the splat operator (`*`)? It sounds like it may help you.

Comment: Depending on what these functions are and what you're using the return values for, it may be better to call these functions in a loop or list comprehension rather than trying to shorten the call syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand that * can be used to unpackage tuples or lists, but I need to associate them with their respective optional arguments and I don't know if * is possible to achieve that.

Comment: @KevinLin Iirc, you can unpack a dictionary that has the same keys as the names of the optional arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question you asked, the answer is yes. You can do almost exactly what you want using keyword argument unpacking.

```
def f(arg1):
    def g(optional_1=0, optional_2=0, optional_3=0):
        return arg1+optional_1+optional_2+optional_3
    return g

optional_variable_pair = {
    'optional_2': 2,
    'optional_3': 3
}

f1 = f(1)
f2 = f(2)
calc_f1 = f1(**optional_variable_pair)
calc_f2 = f2(**optional_variable_pair)
```

If I'm reading your intent correctly, though, the essence of your question is wanting to pass new first arguments with the same successive arguments to a function. Depending on your use case, the wrapper function `g` may be unnecessary.

```
def f(arg1, *, optional_1=0, optional_2=0, optional_3=0):
    return optional_1 + optional_2+optional_3

optional_variable_pair = {
    'optional_2': 2,
    'optional_3': 3
}

calc_f1 = f(1, **optional_variable_pair)
calc_f2 = f(2, **optional_variable_pair)
```

Obviously, if the first argument continues incrementing by one, a `for` loop is in order. Obviously, if you are never using the `optional_1` parameter, you do not need to include it. But, moreover, if you find yourself using numbered arguments, there is a good chance you really should be working with tuple unpacking instead of keyword unpacking:

```
def f(*args):
    return sum(args)

optional_variable_pair = (2, 3)

for i in range(1, 3):
    calc = f(i, *optional_variable_pair)
    # ...do something with calc...
```

You may also be interested in researching `functools.partial`, as well, which can take the place of your wrapper function `g`, and allow this:

```
import functools

def f(*args):
    return sum(args)

f1 = functools.partial(f, 1)
f2 = functools.partial(f, 2)

calc_f1 = f1(2, 3) # = 1 + 2 + 3 = 6
calc_f2 = f2(2, 3) # = 2 + 2 + 3 = 7
```

Answer (score 2):

Any function with multiple optional arguments is a bit smelly because:

1. you get so many argument combinations that it requires a large amount of testing.
2. because of all the options the function has to have alot of conditionals and routes which increase its cyclomatic complexity.

You can apply a refactoring to extract the whole argument list into an Object and have the function work on that object. This works really well if you can find a unifying name that describes your argument list and fits whatever metaphor you are using around the function. You can even invert the call so that the function becomes a method of the Object, so you get some encapsulation.

Comment: What's your opinion on `plt.plot()`? It has a lot of parameters, but I think it's fine. And in terms of passing an object to a function, that's what a dict is like to me.

Comment: Having briefly looked at its documentation I think its pretty smelly. I also think that I don't know enough about its domain to make an informed judgement. The point of smells, isn't that they tell you something IS wrong, they tell you something may well be wrong. In the domain of plt.plot perhaps there is no clearly better way to represent the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You use key-value pairs as function argsuments, for this purpose you can use *args and **kwargs:

```
optional_variable_pair = {
  "optional_1": 1,
  "optional_2": 2,
  "optional_3": 3,
}
calc_f1 = f1(**optional_variable_pair)
calc_f2 = f2(**optional_variable_pair)
```